# How shall i concatenate two or more values/variables to a new variable in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, concatenation

I am pretty much new to laravel(5.2), here i want to concatenate two values say first name and last name during user registration and save it to database, honestly as am new to this whole concept i have very little idea of doing it...it would be great if i could get some help....

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**AuthController.php**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
  protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
             ]);
    }

protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
             ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to save the new value to data base you must register it in you fillable, also to alter the database to accept the new column

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'
];


protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'user_name' => $data['first_name'].' '.$data['last_name'],
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
         ]);
}
```

you may want to remove first_name and last_name.. and store only full name, or you can ignore storing the full name, and in User.php model you can override the toArray() method and make it returns the full name which you can concatenate just like above

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation of two strings in a php concept, it do not relates to laravel in any way. You can easily concatenate two or more string like:

```
$str = $data['first_name'].' '.$data['last_name'];   // concatenate by using space
```

But this does not help you because you are inserting user data into user table which have first_name, last_name columns. So you have to insert them individually.

Comment: ya..i get it sir but sorry as i have very little idea of laravel  i want to know where and how in above code presented code..

Comment: Laravel is nothing just a framework build on core php, what ever php follows laravel also follows

Comment: but sir should i concatenate it in  AuthController.php??

Comment: Why you want to concatenate ?

Comment: To create a fullname using 2 variables first name & last name

Comment: $str = $data['first_name'].' '.$data['last_name']; but your table have two columns one for fname and another for lname

Comment: sorry sir...i got the point of concatenate strings but..i want to know were in the presented code shall i concatenate..?

Answer (score 0):

// to concat with a space in between use

```
$str = $data['first_name'].' '.$data['last_name'];
```

// to concat to one big string without spacing use

```
$str = $data['first_name'].$data['last_name'];
```